# Django Rest Framework: Register User model to Course model

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST API that has a User and Course model defined as:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default=uuid.uuid4)
   username = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=32, unique=True)
   notes = models.ForeignKey('notes.Note', null=True, related_name='notes')
   courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='courses')


class Course(models.Model):
   course_name = models.CharFIeld(max_length=64)
   course_tutor = models.ForeignKey('authentication.User', related_name='tutor', blank=True)
   course_students = models.ManyToManyField('authentication.User', editable=True, related_name='students')
```

My serializers are defined like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_notes_for_user')
    courses = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_courses_for_student')

    def get_courses_for_student(self, obj):
        # What do I do here??

    def get_notes_for_user(self, obj):
        queryset = Note.objects.all().filter(note_owner=obj)
        return queryset.values()

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('id', 'username', 'notes', 'courses')

class CourseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    course_students = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', lookup_field='pk', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Course
       fields = ('course_name', 'course_tutor', 'course_students', )
```

My question is: How do I correctly (and RESTful) register users to courses? *I have thought of an intermediate model such as Subscriptions but I do not know the correct approach.*

The endgoal is to have an User/Course/Activity API that allows certain Users to "subscribe" (**Hence the intermediate Subscription model**) to a certain course/activity. I'm troubling myself over how to implement this and would appriciate additional insights.

If I have failed to provide enough details to resolve this please do tell. I will gladly supply any additional information.

Comment: Is your question about how to implement the creation of `course_students` m2m relationships in REST views ?  
`SerializerMethodField` is necessarily read-only. Is that clear for you ?

Comment: Hello Adrien, I understand `SerializerMethodField` is read-only and yes, my question is exactly that. I am just riddled by the implementation. The only possible solution I see is the implementation of an intermediate model using `through` but I am not sure.